# How to use Gpsd_viewer package

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I came across this package and found it really interesting.however when I tried to use this package using my gps device it is still not changing the map.I am using the same message description as in the package i.e GpSfix and Gpsstatus.It is giving a static longitude and latitude and is showing the same map.I dont think it is subscribing to the fix message.Could you please help me use this package?Thanking you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9433/how-to-use-gpsd_viewer-package/) by [avin111](https://answers.ros.org/users/56/avin111/) on ROS Answers with karma: 83 on 2011-03-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well if u want to use gpsd_viewer u must have record yours bag file,and if u want to see yours map instead od ccny koordinates u must change them in code(http://www.ros.org/doc/api/gpsd_viewer/html/gpsd__viewer_8cpp_source.html) line 126: OsmGpsMapPoint ccny_coord = { 40.818551, -73.948674 }; (OsmGpsMapPoint yours_coordinates ={your_latitude, your_longitude};) - u must enter yours coordinates, that works fine for me
In gpsd_viwer/demo u have demo.launch file so look it and then create yours examlpe.launch file with yours coordinates and execute command : $ roslaunch gpsd_viewer example.launch
It is best that you keep example.bag file in gpsd_viewer/demo.
I hope this helps you.

---

Originally posted by [Jurica](https://answers.ros.org/users/324/jurica/) with karma: 97 on 2011-03-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1